# Is it possible to view/edit code snippets from the inside of Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The snippets manager shows names of snippets, but I don't see any way to see their code here. Or the only option is to go to the folder and manually view/edit files? 
[image: pic]

Comment: @Clearer this question is a _very_ poor fit over there - it would be quickly voted down and closed, see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)  Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with

Comment: @gnat I'll refrain from doing so again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snippet Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.SnippetDesigner) extension lets you [manage existing snippet files](https://github.com/mmanela/SnippetDesigner/wiki/Manage-Existing-Snippets) inside of Visual Studio:

[image]